# Symfony Testing - ClockMock / DateTime

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, mocking, phpunit

I looking for help with creating complex test for our JSON API based application.

Short problem scenario:

- Test create temporary entity (for compare)
- EntityManagerMock is set to wait for **persist($temporaryEntity)**
- Test call real method with some parameters
- Method create entity and try to save at **mocked EM**
- Test fails because time change for 1 second

[image]

We tried to use **ClockMock** but it's work only for class where was called/for namespace. Our method is at other namespace and entity is created in some next.

We looking for solution how to temporary override PHP platform **\DateTime** class - or technique how to use ClockMock for all namespaces/class in project (but only for tests). We tried to modify Symfony based ClockMock - but good way not found :-/.

Is there any way? (I dont want use something like **get_declared_class()** and call with it clockMock::register - because it's very slow soloution for about 15.000 tests :-/.

Thanks all!

Comment: "We looking for solution how to temporary override PHP platform \DateTime class." I'm not following why you would ever need or want to do this.  How would a mock of it help in unit testing?

Comment: Can you show the rilevante part of the code?

Comment: I'm sorry but i must place code to paste bin: http://pastebin.com/ZhBMrq4P - it's simplified but main problem is there. Problem is expectation for persist call - because "new DateTime" sometime generate greater time (when test is running at turn second). There is soloution with register all classes to ClockMock - but it's very time expensive for full project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ClockMock doesn't work for `new \DateTime()` but only on time-based PHP function.

[From the announcement of the features](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-clock-mocking-and-time-sensitive-tests#clock-mocking):

> This means that you don't need to make a single change in your
>   original code, except when using `new DateTime()`, which must be
>   replaced by `DateTime::createFromFormat('U', time())` to use the
>   mocked `time()` function.

So try as suggested: replace any DateTime object creation with the named-constructor with the time function.

Hope this help